# How to run apache hadoop yarn 'ResourceManager' and 'NodeManager' from source code?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I'm learning apache hadoop yarn and want to run it from source code. I got an error when start up 'ResourceManager',I guess it lack of parameter when start up.

Hear is the error

```
org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceStateException: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnException: Failed to initialize queues
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceStateException.convert(ServiceStateException.java:105)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:173)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceInit(CompositeService.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager$RMActiveServices.serviceInit(ResourceManager.java:888)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:164)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.createAndInitActiveServices(ResourceManager.java:1300)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.serviceInit(ResourceManager.java:339)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:164)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.main(ResourceManager.java:1588)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnException: Failed to initialize queues
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler.initializeQueues(CapacityScheduler.java:757)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler.initScheduler(CapacityScheduler.java:342)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler.serviceInit(CapacityScheduler.java:418)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:164)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Queue configuration missing child queue names for root
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacitySchedulerQueueManager.parseQueue(CapacitySchedulerQueueManager.java:234)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacitySchedulerQueueManager.initializeQueues(CapacitySchedulerQueueManager.java:162)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler.initializeQueues(CapacityScheduler.java:748)
    ... 10 more
```

Comment: "Start up" how? You need to compile the source code first, so at that point, there is no difference in using official builds unless you've changed the sources or added different compilation flags...

Answer (score 0):

It is saying that Yarn Resource Manager service starting failed because the Capacity Scheduler is not correctly set.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Queue configuration missing child queue names for root
```

There is a Queue named `root` but something is missing.

Read this for more information : https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.1.1/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/CapacityScheduler.html

If you need more, what is the `capacity-scheduler.xml` configuration file content ?